# How to pass list of PyHandles to function, making separate thread for every handle

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need every directory handle from the list to be addressed in different thread.
My code:

```
while len(handles_list) != 0:
    threading.Thread(target=handle_thread, args=handles_list,).start()
    handles_list.pop(0)

def handle_thread(handle):
    # do stuff with handle
```

Written like this it's giving an error that the def take only one argument - two are given (or more depending on the list's content). So how to start 3 different threads giving them args handles_list[0], handles_list[1] .. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread object expects the target function to have as many arguments as are contained in that list. You are passing the entire list of handles, but the target function expects a single handle.

So, you need to pass a single handle to each thread you create. But the `args` parameter needs to be an iterable whose length is the number of arguments that the target function expects. So you write it like this:

```
for handle in handles_list:
    threading.Thread(target=handle_thread, args=[handle]).start()
```

Or if you'd rather use a tuple than a list:

```
for handle in handles_list:
    threading.Thread(target=handle_thread, args=(handle,)).start()
```

This article gives a concise introduction to argument passing to the thread class: [Python Threading Arguments, Andrew Ippoliti](http://blog.acipo.com/python-threading-arguments/).

Comment: I've tried that... Tried several things before writing here. I've also tried passing handle_list[index] and increment the index. I always get:

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: handle_thread() argument after * must be a sequence, not PyHANDLE  

(That's for every handle in the list)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try now.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! I'll read the article you provided but it feels the issue is with the unpacking. Can you explain with few words what the problem was?

Comment: Second sentence of second paragraph says it.

Comment: I've read it several times, as other sources as well but cannot get how to pass a dictionary like d={ <PyHANDLE:372>:'d\\1\\2'}  to def handle_thread(handle,directory) so I can put the key as handle and directory as directory
    while 1:   
        results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW (
          handle, ...)
for action, file in results:            
            full_filename = os.path.join (directory, file)

Comment: `args=[{'foo': 'bar'}]` Remember, the args parameter needs to be an iterable whose length is the number of arguments that the target function expects.

Comment: But you'd be better passing two elements: `args=[handle, filename]` and declaring the target like this: `def handle_thread(handle, filename)`

Comment: Thank you! Again! args=[{'foo': 'bar'}] worked. I also prefer args=[handle, filename] approach, but I HAVE TO bind the handle to the directory because I use: for dirr in dirs_to_watch:
      if os.path.isdir(dirr):
        handle = win32file.CreateFile (
        dirr,
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        None,
        win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
        None)
        handles_list.append(handle)
        handle_dict.update( {handle: dirr })
Anyway...Thank you!!!